# Can I feed water coming from a water softener into a water heater?

Tags: plumbing, water, water-softener

I'm trying to decide where to place my water softener. I originally planned to put it in the utility closet where city water comes in, but this plan had a [variety of issues](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/91701/is-this-a-workable-water-softener-plan).

My current plan is to re-route cold water going into my (conventional) water heater so that it goes through the softener first. Is there anything I'm not anticipating with this plan? Is there any reason not to route the supply to the water heater as shown below?

The water softener will be in a laundry room with an easily accessible drain. I plan to run Pex through the ceiling.

It seems like a simple approach, but I'm not a plumber so my weakness is not knowing what I don't know.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Can we assume you have a conventional, storage-type hot water heater? Or is your hot water heater a tankless type?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes, it's a conventional water heater.

Comment: I would suggest at least editing the title, to make it clear that the given answer is about whether it’s bad to feed a tank water heater with artificially softened water. It would make it easier for people to find an answer to this question, and help prevent duplicates such as mine.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue with feeding artificially softened water into a storage hot water heater is that softening water makes the water more conductive.  This isn't a big deal, except for the fact that the protective anode in your water heater tank that keeps it from rusting away into oblivion works harder and faster in more conductive water.  This is because corrosion is an electrochemical reaction, and there is actually a small galvanic current flowing through the hot water in your tank and back to the sacrificial anode through the tank wall -- the more conductive the water, the larger this current, and the faster the "battery" created by the sacrificial anode, water, and tank wall discharges, eating up the anode.

As a result of this, feeding softened water into most stock hot water heaters will cause them to die rather quickly of rust -- the anode goes first, then once the anode's gone, the tank itself proceeds to rust out.  If your tank is so equipped, regular anode changes (you may have to change anodes at half the warranty period or less!) are one way to keep the tank from dying; however, a better solution would be to fit the tank with a [powered anode](https://www.waterheaterrescue.com/products/powered-anodes-for-sale.html) -- this uses wall power to produce a small electric current in the tank that suppresses the corrosion reaction by driving it "backwards" if you will.  (Think of the difference between discharging and charging a battery.)

(I have no affiliation with the Water Heater Rescue folks, btw -- they simply do a good job supporting something most people don't think about, and that's how to treat hot water heaters as something other than a throwaway device.)

Comment: Interesting - wouldn't this be an issue for lots of people with whole-house water softening?

Comment: @Tyler -- for folks who plumb soft water to their water heater, yes.

Comment: Never heard of a power anode. What about [dieletric fittings/joints](https://plomberie.fr/system/production/image/image/28031/d640030a.jpg)? Do they serve the same purpose, and do they need to be replaced?

Comment: @Mat -- dielectric fittings are a whole different animal altogether and have nothing to do with this issue

Comment: Okay, thanks. Final point: If the tank corrosion is left unchecked, which is quite easy to do for anyone not familiar with the subject, does it just result in a leak or can the tank explode? If so it might be worth adding a remark about it in your answer.

Comment: @Mat -- the tank'll just leak :P

Comment: Does this impact all water heaters or only electric ones? I ask because I've been feeding soft water into my gas water heater and my last heater lasted more than 25 years without any anode rod change.

Comment: Hrm, maybe if I remember to change the anode rod, the new heater will last 50 years!??!!?

Comment: @FreeMan -- it impacts all water heaters, but yes, with regular anode rod changes, you very well could get 50 years out of a standard tank water heater

Comment: Thanks, TPE. I'll do some digging into what the "regular replacement interval" should be and put a reminder on my calendar. Maybe my grand kids will get to enjoy this HWH as adults... :) Of course, I might not be _able_ to replace the rod, depending on how long it is. Ours in in a root cellar with _very_ low headroom. Had to get a short water heater because there wasn't enough room for the plumbing on top of the one we'd originally picked out...